# Jenkins: ERROR: Error fetching remote repo 'origin' in Window 10 Pro

Tags: git, github, jenkins, fetch, jenkins-job-dsl

`Please somebody help. I am unable to fetch code from remote repo. Repo is public. I am using Windows 10 Pro. Below is detail of error.

####Started by user Muhammad Usman Shamshad
Running as SYSTEM
Building in workspace C:\ProgramData\Jenkins.jenkins\workspace\Jenkins1
The recommended git tool is: NONE
No credentials specified

> C:\Program Files\Git\bin\git.exe rev-parse --resolve-git-dir C:\Projects\ReactApp.git # timeout=10
> Fetching changes from the remote Git repository
> C:\Program Files\Git\bin\git.exe config remote.origin.url https://github.com/musmanshamshad/devproject.git # timeout=10
> ERROR: Error fetching remote repo 'origin'
> your text`hudson.plugins.git.GitE`your text`xception: Failed to fetch from https://github.com/musmanshamshad/devproject.git
> at hudson.plugins.git.GitSCM.fetchFrom(GitSCM.java:999)
> at hudson.plugins.git.GitSCM.retrieveChanges(GitSCM.java:1241)
> at hudson.plugins.git.GitSCM.checkout(GitSCM.java:1305)
> at hudson.scm.SCM.checkout(SCM.java:540)
> at hudson.model.AbstractProject.checkout(AbstractProject.java:1245)
> at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.defaultCheckout(AbstractBuild.java:649)
> at jenkins.scm.SCMCheckoutStrategy.checkout(SCMCheckoutStrategy.java:85)
> at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.run(AbstractBuild.java:521)
> at hudson.model.Run.execute(Run.java:1900)
> at hudson.model.FreeStyleBuild.run(FreeStyleBuild.java:44)
> at hudson.model.ResourceController.execute(ResourceController.java:101)
> at hudson.model.Executor.run(Executor.java:442)
> Caused by: hudson.plugins.git.GitException: Command "C:\Program Files\Git\bin\git.exe config remote.origin.url [https://github.com/musmanshamshad/devproject.git"](https://github.com/musmanshamshad/devproject.git%22) returned status code 128:
> stdout:
> stderr: fatal: not in a git directory

```
at org.jenkinsci.plugins.gitclient.CliGitAPIImpl.launchCommandIn(CliGitAPIImpl.java:2842)
at org.jenkinsci.plugins.gitclient.CliGitAPIImpl.launchCommandIn(CliGitAPIImpl.java:2762)
at org.jenkinsci.plugins.gitclient.CliGitAPIImpl.launchCommandIn(CliGitAPIImpl.java:2757)
at org.jenkinsci.plugins.gitclient.CliGitAPIImpl.launchCommand(CliGitAPIImpl.java:2051)
at org.jenkinsci.plugins.gitclient.CliGitAPIImpl.launchCommand(CliGitAPIImpl.java:2063)
at org.jenkinsci.plugins.gitclient.CliGitAPIImpl.setRemoteUrl(CliGitAPIImpl.java:1662)
at hudson.plugins.git.GitAPI.setRemoteUrl(GitAPI.java:180)
at hudson.plugins.git.GitSCM.fetchFrom(GitSCM.java:987)
... 11 more
    ERROR: Error fetching remote repo 'origin'
   Finished: FAILURE

     Tried everyhing but unable to get the code. Other job is working but in this job it is giving error.`
```

Answer (score 0):

Your Jenkinsfile code would be helpful in debugging the issue, but simply put, the error is that the folder you're running your Git command from is not a git directory. Right before you run your Git commands, run a command to see where you currently are (something like `echo %cd%` if you are running batch commands). Then go to that location on your machine and ensure that the folder exists and that there is a `.git` folder in there as well.

Alternatively, the common practice when using SCMs is that you don't have the repo available at all times, but instead the repo gets cloned each time the job runs. The build is then run on the cloned repo, and the repo is deleted after the build finishes.